# What is the value of $\sum_{r=1}^n\int_{0}^1f(r-1+x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I tried to write the integral as limit of a sum which gives:$$\int_0^1f(r-1+x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}[f(0)+f(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{2}{n})...+f(\frac{n-1}{n})]$$

which i wrote as: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{r}{n})$$

and when I put this in the question, I get a double summation. I don't know how to go further. Kindly suggest.

Btw the answer to this question is $$\int_0^nf(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(r-1+x)dx$ with substitution $u=r-1+x$ we have
$$\int_0^1 f(r-1+x)dx=\int_{r-1}^r f(u)du$$
so
$$\sum_1^n\int_0^1 f(r-1+x)dx=\int_{0}^n f(x)dx$$

Comment: Thanks! Btw, is there any way this can be solved as limit of a sum? I am 100% fine with the answer you wrote but this question was given in definite integral as the limit of a sum exercise so just wondering if there's any?

Comment: @Cheapstrike For summation we must have $\Delta x=\Big((r+1)-1+x\Big)-(r-1+x)=r\to0$ but It does not occur.

Answer (score 3):

As a hint: try to substitute $u=r+x-1$.

(This would typically be a comment, but I do not, alas, have enough reputation...)

Comment: I think you do now. Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle  \mathfrak{I}:=\sum_{r=1}^n \int_0^1 f(r+x-1) \,\text{d} x$. Leting $u:=r+x-1$ we have $\dfrac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}=1 $ . If $x=0$ we have $u=r-1 $, and if $x=1$ we have $u=r$. Therefore:

$$\begin{align}\mathfrak{I}=&\sum_{r=1}^n \int_{r-1}^r f(u) \, \text{d}u\\
  \end{align}$$
But we know that $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f \,+ \int_b^c f = \int_a^c f $. Therefore :
$$\boxed{\,\,\,\mathfrak{I} =\int_{0}^n f(x) \, \text{d}x\,\,\,\,\,}
$$

Comment: Brother how did you conclude $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f \,+ \int_b^c f = \int_a^c f$ From this  $\begin{align}\mathfrak{I}=&\sum_{r=1}^n \int_{r-1}^r f (u) \, \text{d}u\\
  \end{align}$ .Is it some kind of formula or i need knowledge of riemann integral for this?

Comment: @KislayTripathi it's the sum of areas. Think about the integrals as areas under a graph - if you add the area from $a$ to $b$ and the area from $b$ to $c$ together, wouldn't it be the same as the area from $a$ to $c$?

Comment: Is a way to "glue" togheter the areas. Consider a function $f$ and $a<b<c$. The $\displaystyle \int_a^c f $ (area from $a$ to $c$) can be cuted in a certain $b$. Therefore the area will bem the sum of those areas, wich are $\displaystyle \int_a^b f $ (area from $a$ to $b$) and $\displaystyle \int_b^c f$ (area from $b$ to $c$). Literally a slice haha.

Answer (score 1):

$\int _0^1 f (r+x-1)=\int _0^1 f (r-x) $ let $r-x=u $ thus $dx=-du $ hence we have $I=\sum _1 ^n -\int _r ^{r-1} f (u)du =\sum _1 ^n \int _{r-1} ^r f (u)du =\int _0 ^n f (x)dx $

Comment: from Second last to last step, is it a formula?

Comment: The disappereance of - sign?

Comment: Its a known fact that $\int _a^b f (x)dx=-\int _b ^a f (x)dx $ . I hope its clear now.

Comment: please tell me about The disappereance of summation sign?

Comment: I think you should read basic theorems of integration you can then answer your question yourself;)

Comment: ok then please please please suggest me a book

Comment: I think Thomas calculus may have it